# Reflow/Layout performance for large application

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, dom

I am using GWT to build a HTML application where the performance is correct in general.

Sometimes, it can load many objects in the DOM and the application becomes slow. I used Chrome Developer Tools Profiler to see where that time was spent (under Chrome once the app is compiled ie no GWT overhead) and it is clear that the methods **getAbsoluteLeft()/getBoundingClientRect()** consume the major part of this time.

Here is the implementation used under Chrome (com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplStandardBase) :

```
private static native ClientRect getBoundingClientRect(Element element) /*-{
  return element.getBoundingClientRect && element.getBoundingClientRect();
}-*/;

@Override
public int getAbsoluteLeft(Element elem) {
  ClientRect rect = getBoundingClientRect(elem);
  return rect != null ? rect.getLeft()
     + elem.getOwnerDocument().getBody().getScrollLeft()
     : getAbsoluteLeftUsingOffsets(elem);
}
```

This makes sense to me, as the more elements in the DOM, the more time it may take to calculate absolute positions. *But it is frustrating because sometimes you know just a subpart of your application has changed whereas those methods will still take time to calculate absolute positioning, probably because it unnecessarily recheck a whole bunch of DOM elements*. My question is not necessarily GWT oriented as it is a browser/javascript related problem :

*Is there any known solution to improve GWT getAbsoluteLeft/javascript getBoundingClientRect problem for large DOM elements application ?*

I did not find any clues on the internet, but I thought about solution like :

- (reducing number of calls for those methods :-) ...
- isolate part of the DOM through iframe, in order to reduce the number of elements the browser has to evaluate to get an absolute position (although it would make difficult components to communicate ...)
- in the same idea, there might be some css property (overflow, position ?) or some html element (like iframe) which tell the browser to skip a whole part of the dom or simply help the browser to get absolute position faster

**EDIT :**

Using Chrome TimeLine debugger, and doing a specific action while there are a lot of elements in the DOM, I have the average performance :

- Recalculate style : nearly zero
- Paint : nearly 1 ms
- Layout : nearly 900ms

Layout takes 900ms through the getBoundingClientRect method. This page list [all the methods triggering layout in WebKit](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html), including getBoundingClientRect ...

As I have many elements in the dom that are not impacted by my action, I assume **layout** is doing recalculation in the whole DOM whereas **paint** is able through css property/DOM tree to narrow its scope (I can see it through MozAfterPaintEvent in firebug for example).

Except grouping and calling less the methods that trigger layout, **any clues on how to reduce the time for layout ?**

Some related articles :

- [Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solve my problem : *getBoundingClientRect* was triggering a whole *layout* event in the application, which was taking many times through heavy CSS rules.

In fact, layout time is not directly proportional to the number of elements in the DOM. You could draw hundred thousands of them with light style and layout will take only 2ms.

In my case, I had two CSS selectors and a background image which were matching hundred thousands of DOM elements, and that was consuming a huge amount of time during layout. By simply removing those CSS rules, I reduce the layout time from 900ms to 2ms.

Answer (score -1):

The most basic answer to your question is to use [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), also called delayed evaluation. The principle is that you only evaluate a new position when something it depends upon has changed. It generally requires a fair amount of code to set up but is much cleaner to use once that's done. You'd make one assignment to something (such as a window size) and then all the new values propagate automatically, and only the values that need to propagate.