# How to calculate the position (x,y) of an element on the page without triggering reflow using Dart (in js)?

Tags: dart, reflow

I calculate the position of an element in the page using Dart (compiled to JS). However I read that this might trigger a reflow, that would make this costly in time? is that true?

[Reflow/Layout performance for large application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234214/reflow-layout-performance-for-large-application)

```
Position offset(Element elem) {
  final docElem = document.documentElement;
  final box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  double left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft;
  double top = box.top  + window.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop;
  int width = box.width.truncate();
  int height = box.height.truncate();
  return new Position(left.truncate(), top.truncate(),
                      width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to minimizing reflows is to batch your reads and writes. A read might trigger a reflow if there are pending writes that happened before it, but sequential reads will not trigger reflows. In isolation it's hard to tell whether this will trigger a reflow or not. You can protect against it by requesting a reflow first with `requestAnimationFrame`. This helps when you have multiple reads and want to trigger just a single reflow before all of them, but they must all use `requestAnimationFrame`.

In Dart we give you a `animationFrame` property that returns a `Future` to be more idomatic.

The tricky part is that since `animationFrame` and `requrestAnimationFrame` are asynchronous, your `offset` function must be to, and return a `Future<Position>`. This will necessarily cause all callers to be async too.

```dart
Future<Position> offset(Element elem) {
  return window.animationFrame.then((_) {
    final docElem = document.documentElement;
    final box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    double left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft;
    double top = box.top  + window.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop;
    int width = box.width.truncate();
    int height = box.height.truncate();

    return new Position(left.truncate(), top.truncate(),
                        width, height);
  });
}
```